# Using AtomicBoolean instead of synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, atomicboolean

Say I have a class with 2 instance variables and the following methods (simplified for this question):

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private boolean running;

public MyClass() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        running = false;
    }
}
public void methodA() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        running = true;
    }
}
public void methodB() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        if (!running) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I was looking at this code, and after reading about `AtomicBoolean`, I thought that one might fit here, especially after looking at the `MyClass` constructor and `methodA`. I wasn't too sure about `methodB` though.

Assuming these methods could get called by multiple threads, would the following be thread-safe?:

```
private AtomicBoolean running;

public MyClass() {
    running = new AtomicBoolean(false);
}
public void methodA() {
    running.set(true);
}
public void methodB() {
    if (!running.get()) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Will `running.get()` be guaranteed to see an update via `running.set(true)` or `running.set(false)` from another thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, a simple `volatile boolean` would be enough, since you only seem to be doing atomic operations. AtomicBoolean is useful if you need the methods such as `compareAndSet`.

So in answer to your question, yes, when using a `volatile boolean` or an `AtomicBoolean`, other threads will see the updates to the variable.

Comment: I am not so sure. If there are multiple readers and _one_ writer, then perhaps _volatile_ guarantees are enough. But the moment there are multiple writers, I am not sure if use of _volatile_ is guaranteed.

Comment: Look at the source for AtomicBoolean - it is basically a volatile boolean in an object, if you don't use the compareAndSet methods. Multiple writers are not a problem, in either case.

Comment: According to [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html) (not sure how accurate it is), apparently it is okay if there are multiple writers as long as the new written values don't depend on the previous value, but as soon as you need to check the previous value then set a new one based on the previous one, then `volatile` is not enough.

Comment: Exactly: this is when you need methods such as compareAndSet (you do the affectation depending on the previous value)

Comment: Agree, in this case, the use of `AtomicBoolean` is equivalent to use of `volatile boolean`.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade,  Equivalent in function, but using `AtomicBoolean` is more of a modern style.  Style is important if you're collaborating with other developers.  The more you can make your code look like theirs, the more willing they will be to read it, comment on it, etc.

Comment: I disagree. AtomicBoolean introduces cumbersome "get" and "set" calls instead of normal read and write. Also, you can have concurrency on variables other than boolean or integer. It is important to understand the meaning of volatile and to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking these code blocks are not equal for `methodB`, because reading `volatile` variable does not create synchronization order.

Imagine you have some other field `int x = 42` in your class, that is updated in methodB:

```
public void methodB() {
    if (!running.get()) {
        return;
    }
    if (x < 50) x++; // just example
}
```

Then you have several threads that call `methodB`:

- when using synchronized keyword, updates are safe and visible to all threads.
- when using AtomicBoolean/volatile visibility is broken

If there is no such case with variable updates and the task is just to guarantee visibility between methodA - methodB sequence, then it's OK - AtomicBoolean is enough for that.

Comment: You say if I "change some variable"...Do you mean if I change it inside the synchronized block for case 1 and right after the if block that uses the AtomicBoolean/volatile in case 2?

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix added an example

Comment: Right, the increment of `x` isn't thread-safe. In the actual code there are no unsafe updates that occur after the if-block, so I think I should be okay.

Comment: The visibility of `running` is not broken by the use or `volatile` or `AtomicBoolean`, IMO.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade the example is about X variable

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From the Javadoc of `AtomicBoolean`:

> A {@code boolean} value that may be updated atomically.

This means that any update to `AtomicBoolean` is *indivisible*. So, I would consider such use of `AtomicBoolean` to be *thread safe*.

You should still consider making the declaration of `AtomicBoolean` final:

`private final AtomicBoolean running;`

Comment: Any update to any `boolean` variable is indivisible.  The `AtomicXxxxxxx` classes buy you two things:  (a) They give you `volatile`-like access to the primitive value, and (b) they give you lock-free implementations of `getAndSet()`, `compareAndSet()`, `incrementAndGet()`, etc.